# Uploading a file that is of [object File] to Parse and getting [object Object] when queried back

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to upload picture files to parse but I am so lost. I feel so defeated... Sigh... anyhow, I tried to modify the code on this website: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api, in order to upload my files unto Parse.

this is my html:

```
<div>
    <form id="pictureUploadForm">
        Select an image file: 
        <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        <input type="submit" id="pictureButton"  value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

To upload my image file to Parse, I wrote this (it works, btw):

```
var PictureUploads = Parse.Object.extend("PictureUploads");
var pictureUploads = new PictureUploads();

window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        alert(file);
        var PictureUploads = Parse.Object.extend("PictureUploads");
        var pictureUploads = new PictureUploads();

        pictureUploads.set("pictureFile", file);

        pictureUploads.save(null, {
            success: function(pictureUploads) {

        },
            error: function(pictureUploads, error) {
            print("didn't work");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, if you notice the `alert(file)`, it will alert `[object File]`. And in order to retrieve it, I wrote this (and this works as well):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var query = new Parse.Query(PictureUploads);

    query.get("yAIyFJPvFj", {
        success: function(pictureUploads) {
            var file = pictureUploads.get("pictureFile");
            alert(file);
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            alert("didn't work but don't get mad"); 
        }
    });
});
```

But the problem is, when I retrieve the file which is saved as an object in Parse via `var file = pictureUploads.get("pictureFile");` and I `alert()` the `file`, I get `[object Object]`. But I can't work with an `[object Object]` because I tried to run the rest of the code provided so graciously on the tree house website, it didn't work.

So my questions are, when I query, why does it return an `[object Object]` and is it possible to somehow modify the `[object Object]` so that it becomes an  `[object File]`. Please. Help me... I am dying...

Comment: What does the response you get on query success actually contain (`pictureUploads`)? If you use wireshark or Firebug you can see what the response was and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: so what do you want saved file URL or something else ?

Comment: on parse.com for .net you get oject not file and you get the url with object.Url. Maybe this is your case is useful

Comment: Don’t use `alert`, use `console.log`, and then use your browser console to inspect the object, so that you can see what properties it actually contains.

Comment: or use `alert(JSON.stringify(file))`